# Why Group By is not working as expected in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I m doing a query and it is showing me the output but not as expected. 
[image]

Above image it is giving me two extra row (blue indicator) after doing group by which not should be exists in the output. Here is my query

```
SELECT som.customer_po,
       pro.product_id,
       pro.product_name,
       som.mo_id,
       ri.status
FROM schema_order_map som
JOIN product pro ON som.label_reference_id = pro.product_id
JOIN risk_information ri ON som.customer_po = ri.customer_po
WHERE ri.created_by = 18
  AND ri.product_id = som.label_reference_id
GROUP BY som.customer_po,
         pro.product_id,
         product_name,
         som.mo_id,
         ri.status
```

I tried different way but it is giving me the same result.

Comment: You have included `mo_id` in the `group by` and those two rows have different values in that column so they are not "collapsed" into the same group . What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: Aren't they appearing because `mo_id` is part of the `SELECT/GROUP BY`?

Comment: without mo_id in the group by .. query will not execute. it say's, it must be appeared in the group by

Comment: Try removing `mo_id` from the `GROUP BY` _and_ the `SELECT`.

Comment: I really Need mo_id in this query..  and after removing it  as you mentioned. it's give me the same result.  but somehow I made a solution but i don't know whether it is best practice or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solves my problem somehow. but i don't know it is best practice or not

```
SELECT max(som.customer_po) AS customer_po,
       max(pro.product_id) AS product_id,
       max(pro.product_name) product_name,
       max(som.mo_id) mo_id,
       max(ri.status) AS risk_status
FROM schema_order_map som
JOIN product pro ON som.label_reference_id = pro.product_id
JOIN risk_information ri ON som.customer_po = ri.customer_po
WHERE ri.created_by = 18
  AND ri.product_id = som.label_reference_id
GROUP BY som.customer_po,
         pro.product_id
```